# Subroutine for Reading Data in Database and Display Data

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb

I made a subroutine to read data from database(MS Access) and display it in textboxes. I use an OleDbDataAdapter to fill the DataTable which I will use to show the data in the textboxes. Is there something wrong with what I have done like failing to dispose something that should be properly disposed? Any comment or changes to make it look better or simpler or faster or proper?

strConnection - contains the database connection string

strCommand - contains the string for the sql command

```
Public Sub readQuery(ByVal strCommand As String, ByRef dtTable As DataTable)
    dtTable.Clear()
    Using dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        dbConnection.Open()
        Dim dbCommand As New OleDbCommand(strCommand, dbConnection)
        Using dbReader As OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
            If dbReader.HasRows Then
                Dim dbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(strCommand, dbConnection)
                dbAdapter.Fill(dtTable)
            Else
                MsgBox("No data matches your search.")
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're using .NET, I always suggest following the notation. Instead of MsgBox, use MessageBox.Show() etc

Comment: Ok. I use MsgBox because I only need to display a warning. Other than that?

Comment: Looks reasonable enough. I'm not a fan of using ByRef, but as long as it's well documented and users of that method know you're passing by reference (you'll be amazed at how many developers do not understand how ByRef works), it's all good.

Comment: I added dtTable.Clear before creating a connection so that the data table won't have anything in it and the data won't append. That is okay, right?

Comment: First thing that jumps out is that you don't need to use both a datareader and a dbadapter/datatable - typically you would use one or the other.